# gunicorn ModuleNotFound error, was working previously

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

I have a docker-compose file that was working fine until today and it just started throwing an error when I try to start up my webserver with gunicorn.  The logs look something like:

```
    flask_apis  | [2019-09-05 21:20:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
flask_apis  | [2019-09-05 21:20:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
flask_apis  | [2019-09-05 21:20:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
flask_apis  | [2019-09-05 21:20:04 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
flask_apis  | [2019-09-05 21:20:04 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
flask_apis  | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
flask_apis  |     worker.init_process()
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
flask_apis  |     self.load_wsgi()
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
flask_apis  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
flask_apis  |     self.callable = self.load()
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
flask_apis  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
flask_apis  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
flask_apis  |     __import__(module)
flask_apis  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fintech'
flask_apis  | [2019-09-05 21:20:04 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
flask_apis  | [2019-09-05 21:20:04 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
flask_apis  | [2019-09-05 21:20:04 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
flask_apis  | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
flask_apis  |     worker.init_process()
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
flask_apis  |     self.load_wsgi()
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
flask_apis  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
flask_apis  |     self.callable = self.load()
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
flask_apis  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
flask_apis  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
flask_apis  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
flask_apis  |     __import__(module)
flask_apis  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fintech'
```

My dockerfile looks like

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

And my docker-compose file for that server:

```
services:

  api:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: flask-pywren
    container_name: flask_apis
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 fintech.flask_entrypoint:app
    env_file:
     - ./docker.env
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
```

The funny thing is I can open the sh in side the docker image:

```
docker run -it flask-pywren sh
```

And run

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 fintech.flask_entrypoint:app
```

and gunicorn starts up fine.  The only thing I can think of is that `docker-compose` is not starting in the `WORKDIR`?  I have also added `working_dir: "/app"` to the docker-compose file but that didn't work either. I am really at a loss as to why this suddenly isn't working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see in the logs it very clear that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fintech'`.

You need to install `fintech`.

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install fintech
```

As far docker-compose that can change the behaviour of docker is

```
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
```

It will override all thing under `/app` that copied during build time `COPY . .`

[understanding-docker-and-docker-compose](https://medium.com/peaksware-product-development/understanding-docker-and-docker-compose-5f1b63d6ec0a)